# Does distribute_reads gem support load balancing replicas for Amazon Aurora?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-aurora

I use [distribute_reads](https://github.com/ankane/distribute_reads) gem and have below `database.yml` setup:

```
default: &default
  url: postgresql-makara:///
  makara:
    sticky: true
    connections:
      - role: master
        name: primary
        url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %> # aurora writer endpoint 
      - name: replica
        url: <%= ENV["REPLICA_DATABASE_URL"] %> # aurora reader endpoint 

development:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Amazon Aurora creates additional replica when CPU increased, but the new replica seems not to be used at all. We expect connections from overload replica to being transferred to the new one. I was already reading that connections should somehow reconnect to direct to new replica.

I would expect the gem to work in similar way that [fresh_connection](https://github.com/tsukasaoishi/fresh_connection) gem provides. Below schema from readme and how replicas behave in our app.

```
Rails -------+---- DB Master
             |
             |                     +------ DB Replica1 # CPU 99% 500 connections
             |                     |
             +---- Loadbalancer ---+
                                   |
                                   +------ DB Replica2 # CPU 5% 0 connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below settings in `database.yml` helped us to distribute traffic across read replicas.

```
idle_timeout: 5
reaping_frequency: 5
```